# How to create GeoTiff file from .h5 file?

Tags: java, geotiff-tiff, hdf

I have .h5 file containing Latitude, Longitude and Dataset(I m working multiple type of dataset).And I want GeoTiff file of it contains all Information related to GeoTiff. So is there any way to create GeoTiff from .h5 file?
Or is that ok to create Tiff image from .h5 and create GeoTiff image from it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to provide some more details, please?  For example, are you using any GIS software?  Where does your *.h5 file come from?  What precise steps have you tried and where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: Unknown file format for me, but is it perhaps this one http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html?

Comment: It depends whether the coords are regular, rectilinear or curvilinear. Yes, easy if regular, ootions available for the other. Try gdal_translate file.h5 out.tif as a hopeful startbut note the structure possible in h5 is more general than gtiff. It depends on the file and the intention

Comment: How did you solve this?